# How to format output in Posh Server (Powershell web server)?

Tags: powershell, poshserver

I am currently trying the Powershell web server PoSH (http://poshserver.net/) for some administration reports. But i don't know how to format ouput.

From the start: i start the console with the default shortcut, with admin rights. I type `Import-Module PoSHServer`, then `Start-PoSHServer`. The web server starts, then i create a simple index.ps1 file, with just one line of code in the body section: $(command).

For example, i want to use the `Get-Service Mpssvc` command, but what i obtain is :

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController
```

I try `Get-Service MpsSvc | Select Name,Status`. Output:

```
@{Name=MpsSvc; Status=Running}
```

Same thing for cmdlets `Get-Process`, i have an output with list of processes but it appears like this: `System.Diagnostics.Process (AcroRd32)` ...

However, some cmlets just like the `Get-Date` (used in the Posh demonstration web page) works fine and have a "normal" output.

I read the documentation, but there is no example which can help me for that.

How can i write powershell code to obtain a "clean" and console-like output?

Comment: What output does `Get-Service -Name "MpsSvc"` gives you?

Comment: The same output: `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`

Comment: And other services, like `lmhosts`, `Netlogon`, etc? Same output? Try also running as administrator.

Comment: Same ouput for other services. The `Get-Service` cmdlet without parameter returns a list of `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController
`. About the rights, the webserver must be anyway launched with admin rights.

Comment: This has to be a console issue. `Get-Service` seems to be returning the right type and objects because you can select the properties and they are returned as a hashtable. Console just doesn't seem to know how to interpret them. How did you start powershell? Try starting it from cmd. Also, afais, this has nothing to do with poshserver: `Get-Service` and `Get-Process` are loaded by default in powershell. So I am out of ideas...

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question isn't clear. In fact, i start the console with the default shortcut, with admin rights. I type `Import-Module PoSHServer`, then `Start-PoSHServer`. The web server starts, then i created a simple index.ps1 file, with just one line of code in the body section: `$(Get-Process)`. I edit my question now to add these détails. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded and installed Posh-Server yesterday after reading this post.

If you want output to look like console inside a web-page you are probably looking at this from the wrong angle, you need to think string not console. Your code is supposed to be running inside of a here-string, in the example. So I got the hint here that the standard console formatter does not apply, posh-server will use whatever it wants to to turn your returned object into a STRING!. Your code output will get turned into a string using whatever formatter it deems applies unless you explicitly return a string - which the example script does correctly do. So try this on the console

```
get-process "power*" | out-string -width 80
```

And then try it in your posh-server script. 
You probably really wanted this:

```
Get-Service MpsSvc | Select Name,Status | out-string -width 120
```

Hope that helps - I think the lack of examples in this project is a good thing because this is really a very simplistic web-server; lots of conceptual thinking required before you even start :) .

Comment: Thanks, it works. I thought that PoshServer was easier, but after seeing that, im wondering what are the other solutions to have a web interface for Powershell Admin scripts. Maybe Poshboard...